# Ionic build error - wrong gradle folder

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, ionic3

I have an error when trying to compile the app.

It's a really simple app and it seems that the ionic part resolves well.

I get the following error:

```
[07:35:18]  lint finished in 7.39 s
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121
El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android --release (exit code 1).
```

After running `cordova build android --release --verbose` I get this:

```
...bunch of logs

This app does not have additional resource files defined
Prepared android project successfully
No scripts found for hook "after_prepare".
No scripts found for hook "before_compile".
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121
Running command: cmd "/s /c ""C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.4\bin\gradle" -p C:\Users\USER\WebStormProjects\AppProjectFolder\platforms\android wrapper -b C:\Users\USER\WebStormProjects\AppProjectFolder\platforms\android\wrapper.gradle""
El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada.
Command finished with error code 1: cmd /s /c ""C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.4\bin\gradle" -p C:\Users\USER\WebStormProjects\AppProjectFolder\platforms\android wrapper -b C:\Users\USER\WebStormProjects\AppProjectFolder\platforms\android\wrapper.gradle"
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
```

When I look at the folder `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.4\bin\gradle` it doesn't exists

The only one that exists is `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\gradle\gradle-4.1\bin`

I think it has to do with that but I don't know how to change the folder

Thank you all in advance

Comment: I get a similar problem when building with Cordova directly (after upgrading to Android Studio 3; short-term solution is to downgrade to Android Studio 2.x Console output:
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
   > Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.1. Current version is 3.3. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /Users/chrisbull/Kiln/MA_Demo-Apps/launcher/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-4.1-all.zip

Comment: In my case I had the same issue before update and after update. I thought updating could solve the problem